# Merge records for overlapping dates

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have requirement merge records in PySpark dataframe for overlapping dates.
`MIN` of start date and `MAX` of end data would be the start and end date of overlapped records.

Sample records:

Input data

```
Item Code          Item name     Start_date       End_date
==============     =========     ===========      ===========
111                Item1        15-May-2004      20-Jun-2004
111                Item1        22-May-2004      07-Jun-2004
111                Item1        20-Jun-2004      13-Aug-2004
111                Item1        27-May-2004      30-Aug-2004
111                Item1        02-Sep-2004      23-Dec-2004
222                Item2       21-May-2004      19-Aug-2004
```

Output should be like

```
Item Code         Item name      Start_date       End_date
==============    =========      ===========      ===========
111               Item1          15-May-2004      30-Aug-2004
111               Item1          02-Sep-2004      23-Dec-2004
222               Item2          21-May-2004      19-Aug-2004
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check for overlaps by getting the latest `End_date` in the previous rows, group the rows using the rolling sum of the overlap criterion, and aggregate the earliest and latest dates.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'Start_date', 
    F.to_date('Start_date', 'dd-MMM-yyyy')
).withColumn(
    'End_date', 
    F.to_date('End_date', 'dd-MMM-yyyy')
).withColumn(
    'last_date', 
    F.max('End_date').over(
        Window.partitionBy('Item Code', 'Item name').orderBy('Start_date').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)
    )
).withColumn(
    'group', 
    F.sum(
        F.coalesce(
            F.col('Start_date') >= F.col('last_date'), 
            F.lit(False)
        ).cast('int')
    ).over(
        Window.partitionBy('Item Code', 'Item name').orderBy('Start_date')
    )
).groupBy(
    'Item Code', 'Item name', 'group'
).agg(
    F.date_format(F.min('Start_date'), 'dd-MMM-yyyy').alias('Start_date'), 
    F.date_format(F.max('End_date'), 'dd-MMM-yyyy').alias('End_date')
).drop('group')

df2.show()
+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|Item Code|Item name| Start_date|   End_date|
+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|      222|    Item2|21-May-2004|19-Aug-2004|
|      111|    Item1|15-May-2004|30-Aug-2004|
|      111|    Item1|02-Sep-2004|23-Dec-2004|
+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

Behind the scenes before grouping:

```
+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+-----+
|Item Code|Item name|Start_date|  End_date| last_date|group|
+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+-----+
|      222|    Item2|2004-05-21|2004-08-19|      null|    0|
|      111|    Item1|2004-05-15|2004-06-20|      null|    0|
|      111|    Item1|2004-05-22|2004-06-07|2004-06-20|    0|
|      111|    Item1|2004-05-27|2004-08-30|2004-06-20|    0|
|      111|    Item1|2004-06-20|2004-08-13|2004-08-30|    0|
|      111|    Item1|2004-09-02|2004-12-23|2004-08-30|    1|
+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+-----+
```

Comment: execution time is very high for this process. Is there any way to improve ?
@mck

Comment: One way would be to reduce the size of the window. If you have an estimate of how far the overlapping would happen (e.g. at most across 20 rows), then you can change the `rowsbetween` to `(-20,-1)`.